# DownloadPipelineArtifact task fails in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-artifacts

I am trying to download the artifacts in a pipeline which were published in another pipeline. Here are the relevant lines from the yaml file:

I specify the source pipeline as a resource:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: name
      project: projekt
      source: source
```

Then here is the download task:

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: $(resources.pipeline.Build.projektID)
      pipeline: $(resources.pipeline.Build.pipelineID)
      buildVersionToDownload: $(resources.pipeline.Build.runID)
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'artifact-name'
      downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build/artifact-name'
    displayName: 'Download Artifact'
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Starting: Download Artifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Download Pipeline Artifacts
Description  : Download build and pipeline artifacts
Version      : 2.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
##[error]Unreachable code!
Finishing: Download Artifact
```

If I remove the variables then it works, but I need to use those variables to download the specific version of the source pipeline. What am I doing wrong?
I implemented this based on the MS documentations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistake in `buildVersionToDownload`. You should put there `specific`. And pass `resources.pipeline.Build.runID` as `pipelineId`. Set also `specificBuildWithTriggering` to true.

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: $(resources.pipeline.Build.projektID)
      pipeline: $(resources.pipeline.Build.pipelineID)
      pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.Build.runID)'
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      specificBuildWithTriggering: true
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'artifact-name'
      downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build/artifact-name'
    displayName: 'Download Artifact'
```